# How do I get the author of a discord message and then DM him?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I scan a message for a word and if the message contains that word, DM the author of the message?
Here's the code so far -

```
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        word_list = ['Idiot','noob','dumb']
        for word in word_list:
            if word in message.content:
                if message.author == 'ClientUser':
                    return
                member: discord.member
                member = message.author.name
                channel = await member.create_dm()
                await channel.send(f'Please do not say this word - {word}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can get the user by `message.author` and to message that specific user, we can do it by

```
await message.author.send(f'Please do not say this word - {word}')
```

but we just need to check for members and not for bot message! so we do

```
if message.author.bot != True:
    await message.author.send(f'Please do not say this word - {word}')
```